# What is the best practice of dockerizing a monolit ASP.net application?

Tags: sql-server, database, docker, kubernetes, redis

Imagine we're going to migrate from a monolithic application to a micro service one.
Currently I use MSSQL server for database and I can make it extendable using a database caching service like Redis.
In this scenario, is it better to use caching service for database or Dockerizing it with SQL Server image and then extend it with Kubernetes?
Or maybe both of them can deploy together for a better result.
Thank for your replies in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a cache like Redis can be a good way to improve the performance of a monolithic application by reducing the load on the database server and speeding up data access. However, if you are planning to migrate to a microservice architecture, it may make more sense to consider using a database service that is designed to scale horizontally, such as a distributed database like Cassandra or MongoDB.

Dockerizing the database with a container image can make it easier to deploy and manage, especially if you are using a container orchestration platform like Kubernetes. However, you should carefully consider the specific requirements and constraints of your application when deciding whether to use a cache or a distributed database, as there are trade-offs involved in each approach.

It is also possible to use both a cache and a distributed database together, depending on the needs of your application. For example, you might use a cache to store frequently accessed data that doesn't change often, while using a distributed database to store more complex data structures that need to be updated frequently. Ultimately, the best approach will depend on the specific requirements and constraints of your application.